# openssl:Error: 'genpkey' is an invalid command

Tags: angular, symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I want to connect my Symfony app with an Angular Client so, I installed the *"lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle"* library to generate a token key but when I try to generate a secret executing:

> openssl genpkey -out config/jwt/private.pem -aes256 -algorithm rsa -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096

it gave me the error that I didn't have **Openssl** so I install it but now it doesn't recognize the **genpkey** command